# how to fix position of wordpress admin pointer(tour)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i want use wordpress pointer in a admin menu.
problem is position of pointer.
when i scroll page, menu fixed, but pointer is going to top (absolute)
my code :

in first of admin page :

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-pointer' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-pointer' );
```

in end of page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('li#toplevel_page_mymenu_admin_page').pointer({
           content: 'test_message',
           position: {
               edge: 'top',
               align: 'center',
           },
           close: function() {

           }
       }).pointer('open');

   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default wp-pointer.js will set pointer position to absolute except the case where the target has position fixed. Using show event you can change pointer CSS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('li#toplevel_page_mymenu_admin_page').pointer({
        content: 'test_message',
        position: {
            edge: 'top',
            align: 'center',
        },
        show: function(event, t){
            t.pointer.css({'position':'fixed'});
        },
        close: function() {

        }
    }).pointer('open');
});
</script>
```